# How to root VIVO Y31L

Tags: rooting

I have tried all the apps like king root,kingoroot and I tried to flash manually also but it fails anyone please try to help

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested on XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/qhow-to-root-vivo-y31l-t3561021), you should first get the firmware of version 1.9.22, then you'll be able to root with KingRoot.